# Prevent sapply returning a 3D array

Tags: r, sapply

If I use `sapply` to apply a function over a vector of arguments and that function returns a data.frame, the output seems to be simplified to a 3D array.

For example:

```
set.seed(42)
fn <- function(i) data.frame(n=i, x=rnorm(2, i+2))
sapply(1:10, fn)
>   [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]       ...     
> n Integer,2 Integer,2 Integer,2 Integer,2  ...
> x Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2 Numeric,2  ...
```

When what I'd actually like is one big data.frame, like that output by:

```
do.call(rbind, sapply(1:10, fn, simplify=F))
>     n         x
> 1   1  3.205999
> 2   1  2.638943
> 3   2  4.758163
> 4   2  3.273295
> ...
```

The same happens if I `Vectorize()` the function. Is there a way to avoid the overhead in making a list of data.frame and then rbinding them?

I feel I'm missing something obvious, but `s/l/vapply` (and `simplify2array`) seem quite tersely documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think of this approach:

```
fn <- function(i) c(i, x=rnorm(n=1, i+2))
data.frame(t(sapply(rep(1:10,each=2), fn)))
```

Comment: Thanks hadn't thought of that. Ideally would leave the (real) function as-is as it is working on data.frames internally, but will accept if no better approach is offered.

Comment: Maybe you can use `reshape()` to do this with format="long"

Answer (score 1):

Okay, take 23 or some such, here is an option that allows you to keep your function unchanged.  Unfortunately this will coerce everything to numeric, which should be okay for your application:

```
mx <- matrix(
  unlist(sapply(1:10, fn))[unlist(lapply(1:4, seq, by=4, len=10))], 
  ncol=2
)
as.data.frame(mx[order(mx[, 1]), ])
```